# Set DataFormatString for MVC3 DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have some issue with displaying date correctly, using the MVC3 *`DateTime`* object.

In the controller, I set *`Date = DateTime.Now`*.

In ViewModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.mm.yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

In View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Date, "Date") 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Date) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.DatoForIntervju, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Output:

```
<input class="datepicker" (...) value="26.09.2011 13:26:16" />
```

However, I want the value to be **26.09.11**.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 17):

change

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.mm.yyyy}")]
```

to

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}")]
```

Then, instead of textboxfor, use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
```

Comment: Good Answer! Had this problem myself with textboxfor. I find this to to be a helpful resource for string format which you may find useful for reference: http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/aspnet20/ASPNET02/aspnet02-07.aspx

Comment: Since `{0:dd.mm.yyyy}` includes the time, wouldn't `{0:dd.mm.yy}` also?

Comment: Yes it would. The format string should be {0:dd.MM.yyyy} or {0:dd.MM.yy}.

Comment: mm = minutes, MM = months

Answer (score 3):

Your viewModel correct (only thing is you need to use "yy" if you want to show short year in C#), but I don't understand what do you do with this code

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Date, "Date")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Date) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.DatoForIntervju, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

I show you how I add *`datepicker`*, in this example *`date`* shows and return from view in correct format:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Date').datepicker({ firstDay: 1, dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', clickInput: true });
        });
    </script>
```