# MVC 3 Validation - Format datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

I want to format my **DateTime** field in razor in a clean way.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Guestbook_Validation))]
public partial class web_GuestBook
{
    // Partial generated EF
}

[Bind(Exclude="Id")]
public class Guestbook_Validation
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? DateEntered { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
@item.DateEntered
```

But its still displaying as `05/01/2009 13:28:14`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DateEntered)` if you want the display format to be used.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[Set DataFormatString for MVC3 DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554446/set-dataformatstring-for-mvc3-datetime/7555471#7555471)

You have to use `EditorFor` in the view and use `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` in your viewmodel - For textbox. To display only, use `DisplayFor`

Comment: I don't want a textbox I just want to display then text. I tried this anyway and it didn't work.