# jQuery time picker and MVC validation - the field must be a date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation, jquery-ui-timepicker

I have a property named `StartDate` in my model. I have used `timepicker` add-on to `jquery.ui`  plugin from [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). It is working fine, but problem is that I'm getting validation error message. How can I change validation so that it passes for date-time.

The model is:

```
public class DateTimePickerTest : EntityBase
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Following is the error message]

I'm mostly following directions given [here on MSDN by Rick Anderson](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4).

Comment: pls also post your model & annotation you are using here.

Comment: @Yasser I have added the model. If you need something else please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Saved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555471/13198).

I have used `DisplayFormat` attribute with `ApplyFormatInEditMode` property set to `true`:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.mm.yy}")]
```